# Conditional creation of a Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to use `np.where` to filter the column speed and where a condition is met assign a value in column `'C'`. For some reason I'm assigning everything as true. It seems to work fine for this person [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) so i'm a little stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

`df["C"] = np.where(df.speed > 3, 'true','false')`

```
   speed   C  
0  3.34    true  
1  0.02    true  
2  0.01    true  
3  8.41    true  
4  0.03    true
```

Comment: Works for me as expected. You're not showing the code behind the dataframe creation itself, but that's probably where the error is. Make a self-contained example that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, should have checked this, Speed is listed as an `object`, not an `int`. I knew it was something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables for speed aren't integers, so this test is failing. It is possible they are objects. If the dataframe is properly initialized with integers, this works as expected.

For example, I can get the output you have here if I make all of the datatypes of the speed column into strings.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this, a wise commenter up above suggested I look at how the dataframe was created, so I looked at the dtypes and found

```
id                       int64
speed                   object
C                       object
```

This code fixes the problem:

```
df['speed'] = df['speed'].astype(float)
```